# Drift: Capture textarea events of Iframe for drift chatbot

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, chatbot, drift

I am trying to capture value entered in textarea of drift chat bot. Is this possible?
Have checked the official website for any solution but drift does not provide any way to access the value sent by user.
https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/drift-events#user-sent-a-message

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the message text via client side javascript.

The only exceptions are

- When a site visitor [clicks on a button](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/drift-events#button-clicked) from within the Drift chat- the text of the button will be included in the `buttonBody` property in the payload
- When a site visitor enters an [email](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/drift-events#email-captured), the email will be included as the `email` property in the payload
- When a site visitor enters a [phone number](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/drift-events#phone-number-captured), the email will be included as the `phone` property in the payload

Drift is built within an iFrame specifically to prevent non-authorized scripts from 'listening-in' on conversations.  To access message text, you'll need to use your [Drift Dev platform](https://dev.drift.com) to create a custom app and use webhooks to listen for new messages.  Here's a guide on how to setup a [custom integration](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/custom-map-integration) that could receive the message text. Take a look here for a more concise [overview](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/quick-start).

You'll want to subscribe to the `new_message` [webhook](https://devdocs.drift.com/docs/webhook-events-1#new-message) to receive a JSON object of the message each time a message is sent.